# Reputation unusually low for answer with high upvotes

Tags: discussion

Why does [**Kenneth L**](https://superuser.com/users/282484/kenneth-l) only have 3506 reputation?  I noticed he has an answer with 1145 up-votes. If I do the math:

```
1145 * 10 (Rep for each up-vote) = 11,450
```

His current reputation is less than 30% of that.  I am sure there is a valid reason but I can't figure it out on my own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rep caps. You can't get more than 200 reputation in a day.

Comment: There are plenty of user that have earned more that 200 reputation in one day, yourself included.  Is the the 300 rep cap per question?  If so, why was that rule put in place?

Comment: Never mind Journeyman Geek, I found my answer at [What is the reasoning behind the reputation cap?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

Comment: [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) is probably a good reason for reputation caps. As for getting more than 200 rep, accepted answers and bounties *after* you hit 200 don't count against caps. I'd add that I've not gotten any rep caps since I got my diamond as far as I can tell

Comment: @JourneymanGeek Is John Skeet Modding SE? or has he legitimately earned that much rep and badges?

Comment: He doesn't mod, he believes more in helping out the questioners than being the police.

Comment: Mods tend to get less rep than regular users in many cases actually. High rep is *sometimes* useful in mod elections - as an indication of engagement, but being a mod often means *less* rep, not more.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek If you notice his rep history, you'll notice he's been earning rep since his account was first created. By the way, it's "Jon", not "John".